# Lower bound placement in summation sigma sign

Tags: math-mode

I have this equation and I would like to have lower bound (`v \in N_i(u)`) exactly **under** the summation symbol and not to the right side of it. How to accomplish it?

[image]

This is my LaTex notation:

[image]

Comment: Can't you just copy/paste the code into your question? That would make it a lot easier for us to help.  Making it compilable wouldn't be bad, either :) (just a short document with `\documentclass{…}\begin{document}…\end{document}`.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/17423.

Comment: @Mico While the answer there would work here, note that this isn't inline math :)

Comment: @SeanAllred -- That posting's title is a bit of a mis-nomer: it's about text-style ("inline math mode") vs display-style ("displayed equation mode"). Anyway, since the OP hasn't indicated whether he/she is loading the `amsmath` package, it's not quite appropriate to suggest using `dfrac` instead of `\frac`...

Comment: @Mico well yes, *I* know that, but others may not see this connection :) it's pretty obscure unless you know how TeX works with math.

Comment: Try `\limits` and `\nolimits` right after the `\sum` (`\prod`, `\int`, ...) symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\limits` can be used after `\sum` to put the bounds below and above instead to the side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}
    \hat{r}_{ui} = \bar r + \sigma_u \cdot
    \frac{
      \sum_{v \in N_i(u)} w_{uv} (r_{vi} - \bar{r}_v) / \sigma_v
    }{
      \sum_{v \in N_i(u)} |w_{uv}|
    }
    \\
    \hat{r}_{ui} = \bar r + \sigma_u \cdot
    \frac{
      \sum\limits_{v \in N_i(u)} w_{uv} (r_{vi} - \bar{r}_v) / \sigma_v
    }{
      \sum\limits_{v \in N_i(u)} |w_{uv}|
    }
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]